# VPCDHCPOptionsAssociation encountered unsupported property DHCPOptionsId

Tags: aws-cloudformation

When i'm trying to create the stack it throws the above error. I've checked and i'm using the correct property value.

I've tried adding a "DependsOn" for DHCPOptions. I've tried using the Fn:GetAtt for the DHCPOptions. None have proved successful.

```
  "DHCPOptions": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::DHCPOptions",
    "Properties": {
      "DomainName": { "Ref": "DNSName" },
      "DomainNameServers": [ "AmazonProvidedDNS" ],
      "Tags": [{
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": {
          "Fn::Sub": "${VPCStackName}-DHCPOPTS"
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "VPCDHCPOptionsAssociation": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCDHCPOptionsAssociation",
    "DependsOn": "DHCPOptions",
    "Properties": {
      "VpcId": { "Ref": "TestVPC" },
      "DHCPOptionsId": { "Ref": "DHCPOptions" }
    }
  },
```

Expecting to pass the DHCPOptionsId from the DHCPOptions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. Just a simple error regarding the casing. 
It should be DhcpOptionsId not DHCPOptionsId